# How do I take the response from Discord OAUTH2 and translate it in to my own UserDetails that I can use throughout my code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I am using Spring Boot + Spring Security OAUTH 2 for my app. I want to use Spring OAUTH2 to "Login with Discord" and then parse the information that discord gives on an authentication success into my own JPA Entity which implements `UserDetails`. Also, I want to implement my own `UserDetailsService` to return that custom user entity that I created.

Basically, I only want Discord to provide unique information about a user to I can construct my own `Account` entity based on the response.

I've read the following articles but I still don't understand how to do it:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-principal-authorities-extractor

https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-oauth2-role-based-authorization

Also, here is my OAuth2 Setup:

Security Config (`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`):

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/web/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/oauth2/authorization/discord").anonymous()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/login").anonymous()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/logout").permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .and()
                    .oauth2Login()
                    .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
                    .tokenEndpoint().accessTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient())
                    .and()
                    .userInfoEndpoint().userService(userService());
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> accessTokenResponseClient() {
        DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient client = new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();

        client.setRequestEntityConverter(new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter() {
            @Override
            public RequestEntity<?> convert(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest oauth2Request) {
                return addUserAgentHeader(Objects.requireNonNull(super.convert(oauth2Request)));
            }
        });

        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> userService() {
        DefaultOAuth2UserService service = new DefaultOAuth2UserService();

        service.setRequestEntityConverter(new OAuth2UserRequestEntityConverter() {
            @Override
            public RequestEntity<?> convert(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) {
                return addUserAgentHeader(
                        Objects.requireNonNull(super.convert(userRequest)));
            }
        });

        return service;
    }

    private RequestEntity<?> addUserAgentHeader(RequestEntity<?> request) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.putAll(request.getHeaders());
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0");

        return new RequestEntity<>(request.getBody(), headers, request.getMethod(), request.getUrl());
    }
}
```

AuthSuccessHandler (`AuthenticationSuccessHandler`)
As you can see for this I am trying to work around the problem by saving a JPA entity based on the information given by discord and only pulling from the database as opposed to getting the current user, which prevents me from using roles and authorities.

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class AuthSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;
    private final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();


    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        AuthenticationSuccessHandler.super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, chain, authentication);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        OAuth2User oAuth2User = ((OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication).getPrincipal();
//        oAuth2User.getAttributes().forEach((s, o) -> {
//            System.out.println(s + " : " + o);
//        });

        Long discordId = Long.parseLong(Objects.requireNonNull(oAuth2User.getAttribute("id")));
        Optional<Account> accountOptional = accountRepository.findAccountByDiscordId(discordId);
        if (!httpServletResponse.isCommitted()) {
            if (accountOptional.isEmpty()) {
                accountRepository.save(getAccountFromOAuth2User(oAuth2User));
            }
            redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, "/dashboard");
        } else {
            log.warn("Response committed");
        }

    }

    private Account getAccountFromOAuth2User(OAuth2User oAuth2User) {
        return new Account(Long.parseLong(oAuth2User.getAttribute("id")),oAuth2User.getAttribute("username"), oAuth2User.getAttribute("discriminator"));
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.client-name=Discord
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.client-id=**CLIENT**
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.client-secret=**SECRET**
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.clientAuthenticationMethod=post
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.authorizationGrantType=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8081/login/oauth2/code/discord
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.scope=identify

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.discord.authorization-uri=https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.discord.token-uri=https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.discord.user-info-uri=https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.discord.user-name-attribute=username
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Most of the code used is from this GitHub repository:

https://github.com/Samurus/spring-boot-discord-oauth-example

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using `CustomUserTypesOAuth2UserService` which lets me use a custom class that implements `OAuth2User`